# I want to add a single record in my database but it doubles the record every time it reaches 2 records

Tags: php, mysql

I am adding records to my database but when I reach 2 same records and add another same records it doubles the entry in the database.

Here is my code:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM grade1 WHERE G1StudNo = '$_POST[cat]' AND G1SCode = '$_POST[subcat]' ");

while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($q)) { 
    if(empty($noticia2['G1Sem']) AND empty($noticia2['G1Year'])){

        mysql_query("UPDATE grade1 SET G1Sem = '$_POST[Sem]', G1Year = '$_POST[Year]'
    WHERE G1StudNo = '$_POST[cat]' AND G1SCode = '$_POST[subcat]'");

    }
    else {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM curriculum WHERE SCode='$_POST[subcat]'"); 

        while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
           $insertSQL1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO grade1 (G1StudNo, G1SCode, G1Sem, G1Year, Semester, YearLevel)
    VALUES ('$_POST[cat]','$_POST[subcat]','$_POST[Sem]','$_POST[Year]','$noticia[Semester]','$noticia[YearLevel]')");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is kinda hard to read... can you format it correctly? Also, in your query, you're not concatenating you need to do '".$_POST[cat]."'

Comment: sorry for the bad coding convention..

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious place to look is in the branch with the `INSERT` clause. My best guess is that the dataset returned from your select statement `select * from curriculum ...` is returning 2 records.

EDIT:

The only time the update clause is called is if both semester and year are empty, probably should be `OR`, since it is an invalid entry if either is empty. I don't understand the second part and why you are checking curriculum table

As far as the insert: it probably should only be used if the recordset from the first query finds no student record. If I am reading it right: currently it is called only if a record IS found but the semester and year are empty.

Comment: still the same output.. it doubles the number of entries in the database it seems that because of the while loop it reads the code many times( equal to the number of records).. i cant find a solution for it..

Comment: i call the curriculum so that i can get the value of Semester(dont be confused with the G1Sem it is not the same.) the first if statements searches the record and if it finds the records it will test if the G1Sem and G1Year is empty if it goes that way it will do the 1st clause but if it is not empty it will do the 2nd clause thats what i am thinking in that code.. but it generates more than one records.. thats my problem.. :(

Comment: `INSERT INTO` creates a new record. `UPDATE` updates an existing record. Also, if SCode in *not* a unique record ID, you *will* wind up executing the `INSERT` more than once. If you are trying to update an exisitng record with the missing information, you must use `UPDATE`